# help installing Smarty template engine

Tags: php, smarty

So I have looked and looked, youtube doesn't have any updated tutorials and the smarty org website doesn't really have a clear FAQ (or maybe I overlooked something?)

I have a virtual dedicated server running CentOS with PHP 5.3.5

I downloaded Smarty 3.0.7, unzipped the file and copied it directly to my server. I rename smart's original folder name to just "smarty" then in the url went to www.sitename.com/smart/demo/

Here is my problem, nothing appears. I went in to make sure that the files were pointing to the smarty.class file. Everything seems to be pointing to where it needs to.

So I thought hmmm, ok myabe PHP5 isn't working so I downloaded Smarty v2 which was based off of PHP4.

Still same problem.

Has anyone had this problem and resolved it?

Comment: Maybe there is an error. Turn on error reporting, and edit the error message into your question if one is present.

Comment: I turned my error reporting on, I use this error_reporting(E_ALL & ~(E_STRICT|E_NOTICE));

Comment: can you post your smarty directory structure?

Comment: also dis you set your directory structure in smarty? `$smarty->setTemplateDir('templates directory');
        $smarty->setCompileDir('templates_c directory');
        $smarty->setConfigDir('configs directory');
        $smarty->setCacheDir('cache directory');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the file permissions correct? Try chmod -R 644 * within the smarty dir.
Also make sure the owners are correct. Something like chown APACHE:DEVGROUP files? All of this depends on your host and how strict it is.

Comment: Humour me and try 7/644 perms. Depending on host, I've seen where X on anything but owner will not be processed by apache/php

Comment: 744 on smarty/* gives me 403 Forbidden, so I did a 777 on smarty/* and I finally got something outputed: /*%%SmartyNocache:19196463704d6b1daf2ca2a5-57149200%%*//*/%%SmartyNocache:19196463704d6b1daf2ca2a5-57149200%%*/

Comment: Quick rundown.
smarty download and extract.
Goto web server document root create a folder named smarty in doc root
Open extracted folder -> goto libs dir and copy all contents into Smarty directory you created.
You should have:
Smarty
    internals
    plugins
    Config_File.class.php
    debug.tpl
    Smarty.class.php
    Smarty_Compiler.class.php
Your installed but now need to create your app Directories in the web root. Something like:
TEST
    smarty
        cache
        config
        templates
        templates_c
This is from some notes I had, so your mileage may vary.